# Wait until specific text will be displayed in drop down - selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have an issue that I try to resolve.
I have a page with 4 dropdowns.
and I want to select value in each one og them.
Since the site is angular I used operation to open a drop down and other to select value.
the problem is that after clicking the dropdown to open, all the values are under the same xpath.
( the values generated after pressing the dropdown)

Example dropdown 1 19 values:
[image]
Pressing drop down 2 32 values with the same xpath
[image]

The problem is after filling dropdown 1, and passing to dropdown 2, the xpath is the same but values not changed quickly enough, So I press drop down 2 and selenium try to find values, but see values of first dropdown.
How can I make selenium (not with thread sleep) to wait until my value exists in the dropdown.

This is my code for searching a value in webelements list (meanning the drop down)

```
   public static void clickOptionInListByXpath(String Xpath, String clickedValue)
    {
        Integer flag = 1;
        WebElement option2;
        WebDriver driver2 = WebDriverMgr.getDriver();
        List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = driver2.findElements(By.xpath(Xpath));
       // for (WebElement option : dropdownOptions  )
        for(int i= 0;i<dropdownOptions.size() && flag == 1;i++)
        {
            option2 = dropdownOptions.get(i);
            System.out.println("\n Option is: " + option2.getText());
            if(option2.getText().equals(clickedValue))
            {

                option2.click();
                flag = 0;


            }
        }
    }
```

This it my code for waiting text to be seen in  single element by xpath with 1 results, not in list (xpath for more than 1 element)

```
 public static void getWebElementByXpathWithWaitTextToBeSeen(String xpath,String text)


      {
            WebDriver driver2 = WebDriverMgr.getDriver();
          //  driver2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(IMPLICIT_WAITE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver2,EXPLICIT_WAITE);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath),text));
        }
```

How I can wait until text exists in web elements list? and it will refresh the list every time ?
p.s I  use sleep it will work however I want code without hard coded sleep
regards

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify the **preconditions** first and please correct me if I am wrong:

1. You have 2 identical web-elements on page that represent 2 drop-downs.
2. Each of them can generate N web-elements which are all identical in scope of the whole document.

The **issue** is: when you get all the drop-down options, there is no way to identify from which drop-down they are.

---

Based on given amount of information I may offer you to start from finding both drop-down elements first, and keeping references to them till you have done all your tests with them.

In this case you will be able to find not **all** the options, but options that are children of specific drop-down, e.g. using
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-

---

Summarizing - find both drop-downs first, and then look for the values not only by xpath, but xpath + parent dropdown.

Comment: for each dropdown there is different id. so I know what dropdown I open. then The values are in the same xpath, and according the dropdown i click the values changed. the problem is that selenuim is to fast, so when i press the scond drop down, the values still from the first drop down in the xpath. since the xpath is the same, i do not understand the answer, since the parent the and the full xpath the same

Comment: Can it be done with fluent wait? to tell selenium wait untill text exists in webelement list?

Comment: I am kinda lost, sorry - do options of drop-down are even children of it in a tree? If yes, and if drop-down IDs are different, they should be ok to differentiate by xpath, because you can include ID in xpath. If no, and it would be weird, the only option would be to validate if list of options has changed after you pressed drop-down 2. What would greatly help is - full cut of HTML with both drop-downs and at least one opened, and xpath you are using